# Simple example to apply the SLLN

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, law-of-large-numbers

I'm trying to find concrete examples of the SLLN theorem. Before, let's see the statement of this theorem precisely from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441923225), page 81:

> **Definition:** We say that $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$, written $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} X$, if
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(\{s:X_n(s)\to X(s)\})=1$$
>
> **Theorem** (The Strong Law of Large Numbers). Let $X_1,\ldots X_n$ be IID. If $\mu=\mathbb E|X_1|\lt \infty$ then
>
> $$\bar X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}\mu$$

I'm thinking about for example the $X\sim Bern(1/2)$, such as the coin experiment where we can define as $X(T)=0$ and $X(H)=1$.

The way I understand the theorem is it states for every $s$ in the outcome from the experiment (except the ones with $P(s)=0$), we have $\bar X_n(s)\to \mu$.

I can't see this in my example. Let's start with $s=H$. Since we already know $\mu =1/2$, we have:

$$\bar X_n(H)=\frac{X_1(H)+\ldots+X_n(H)}{n}=\frac{1+\ldots+1}{n}=1\nrightarrow 1/2$$

as $n$ goes to infinity.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The event of getting all Heads in an infinite number of i.i.d tosses has probability $0$. So what you proved does not contradict SLLN.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, but first I'm taking a finite number $n$ of heads and only after I will take $n$ to go to infinity. It's different, no?

Comment: @user42912 : if you take $n=10$ the probability of getting 10 H is $\frac{1}{2^{10}}\approx 0$

Comment: @tommik could you give me an example that works in this context?

Comment: @tommik another question, following the statement of the theorem, aren't there only two possible situations? for $s=H$ and $s=T$, both with probability 0 as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: I think the logical modifiers may be mixed up in your interpretation. You say that theorem "states for every $s$ in the outcome from the experiment (except the ones with $P(s)=0$), we have $\bar{X}_n(s)\rightarrow \mu$." My interpretation of the theorem is that for all the outcomes $s$ such that $X_n(s) \rightarrow \mu = 1/2$, the probability of getting such an outcome is one. The sample space being used is already the one on infinite draws, and the $\bar{X}_n(s)$ are using information from the first $n$ of them.

Comment: You're thinking of $s$ as being a single outcome for a single toss of a coin. The $s$ here is the outcome of infinite tosses.

Comment: @YacoubKureh I see, this is not clear at all for me from the statement of the theorem

Comment: @user42912 I definitely agree it's not clear or obvious as written...the book you're citing is horrificly terse! I hope it's clear now though :)

Comment: @YacoubKureh let me see, if I got it. We cannot take an specific example as I did, because it's gonna have probability $0$. The $s$ there it's a random event with infinite outcomes in this case, as you said, infinite draws in a coin. Thank you very much to help me

Answer (score 1):

Given that the proof of SLLN is well known and you can find it in a lot of books ([Here](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Ewinkel/bs3a07l9-10.pdf), for example, you can find a very basic proof) I would like to make you think about an intuitive reasoning:

SLLN in your example can be stated in the following way: For $n$ large, calculate the following probability

$$\mathbb{P}\Bigg[\lim\limits_{n}\overline{X}_n=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg]=?$$

Say: toss the fair coin $10,000,000$ times: what is the probability you observe a numbers of H $\rightarrow 5,000,000$?

...I think it is intuitive that this probability is 1.

SLLN provides a proof of this intuition